# Link to second local html file with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to switch from the index.html file to a second html file called projects.html in a PhoneGap App on Android. If I write something like `<a href="projects.html">Second Page</a>` the projects.html page opens, but I get a prompt "[]" and then "usePolling" and then "getPort". In adb logcat the error "D/PhoneGapLog( 3288): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.0.9.6.js: Line 810 : JSCallback Error: Request failed." appears. Looking around on the internet using multiple html files seems to me to be some kind of an issue with phonegap. Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed to phonegap version 1.0. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As a solution for this problem, you can either edit phonegap.0.9.5.js and comment out all lines that contain the prompt() function (there are six lines).

Or you download [PhoneGap 0.9.4](http://phonegap.googlecode.com/files/phonegap-0.9.4.zip) (PhoneGap 0.9.4 doesn't use the prompt() function), extract the phonegap.0.9.4.js file from it, delete phonegap.0.9.5.js from the `assets/www/` directory and place phonegap.0.9.4.js in the `assets/www/` directory instead.

Answer (score 0):

It also happens if you create a PhoneGap Android app following Quickstart page http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have a solution to the above but I was getting the same until I changed the reference to the phonegap.0.9.6.js to not include the version info in each html page . ie just use phonegap.js where you indclude it in the script tags